# Sum of a column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame.

```
LeafId   pidx  pidy   count
  1       x     y       10
  1       x     y       20
  1       x     z       30
  3       b     q       10
  1       x     y       20
```

We can see that there are multiple rows of `pidx = x and pidy = y`

I want to sum the count column and get dataframe df2 as:

```
LeafId   pidx  pidy   count
  1       x     y       50
  1       x     z       30
  3       b     q       10
```

I know one way of doing it:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['pidx','pidy']).agg({'LeafID':'first',count':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

But I want the most efficient way of doing it for a huge DataFrame (millions of records), which will take the least amount of time.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Also, instead of putting `LeafID` inside `.agg()`, can I do the following?

```
df2 = df.groupby(['LeafID','pidx','pidy']).agg({count':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Sort by pidx and pidy, find indices of where either changes then apply sum on the ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need `groupby` by `LeafId` , `pidx` and `pidy` columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
print (df1)
   LeafId pidx pidy  count
0       1    x    y     50
1       1    x    z     30
2       3    b    q     10
```

I try some **timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

L1 = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstu')
L2 = list('efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
df = pd.DataFrame({'LeafId':np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'pidx': np.random.choice(L1, N),
                   'pidy': np.random.choice(L2, N),
                   'count':np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})
#print (df)

print (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy'], as_index=False)['count'].sum())
print (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy']).agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index())

In [261]: %timeit (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy'], as_index=False)['count'].sum())
1 loop, best of 3: 544 ms per loop

In [262]: %timeit (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy']).agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 466 ms per loop
```

Smaller groups `1000` to `10000`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

L1 = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstu')
L2 = list('efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
df = pd.DataFrame({'LeafId':np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'pidx': np.random.choice(L1, N),
                   'pidy': np.random.choice(L2, N),
                   'count':np.random.randint(10000, size=N)})
print (df)

print (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy'], as_index=False)['count'].sum())
print (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy']).agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index())

In [264]: %timeit (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy'], as_index=False)['count'].sum())
1 loop, best of 3: 933 ms per loop

In [265]: %timeit (df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy']).agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 775 ms per loop
```

Comment: 2 questions, would my method of .agg work and if yes , will your answer  be faster than .agg?

Comment: @SRingne Give it a try. Since you said your DF is huge. Let us know the timings.

Comment: @jezrael `.sum()` and explicit `column.sum()` will make a difference here since there is only 1 column?

Comment: @MYGz - I think yes, better is specify column for sum, but if only `4 columns` dataframe it is same.

Comment: @SRingne - I am not sure, but I can test it, but in my opinion timinngs shupld be same or `agg` slowier.

Comment: @jezrael `.agg` is faster I think. `4.17 ms` vs `1.93 ms`.

Comment: @MYGz - interesting, can you share your sample data to timings? `df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)` is problematic for timings, becasue too large groups I think.

Comment: @jezrael Did it on sample data mentioned in question `%timeit df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()` vs `%timeit df.groupby(['LeafId','pidx','pidy']).agg({'count':'sum'})` Did not create large dataset. What are your timings?

Comment: @MYGz - is necessary test in larger dataframe, I try create sample, but it need some time. i am doing on it.

Comment: I add timings, it seems `agg` is faster. Check edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael i guess the time taken depends on what type of data you select and how many sum/agg operations it has to perform.

Comment: @jezrael i support your answer. what i did was appended the df asked in the question multiple times and created a `large dataframe out of it(1.3 million rows)` and i calculated the exact times taken by both the methods. Results are as follows:
`Method using .agg completed in 0.283999919891 seconds
method using groupby and .sum completed in 0.363000154495 seconds`

Comment: @SRingne - Exactly, I try create same dtypes.

Comment: @SRingne - thank you for comment, `agg` is a bit faster, but small difference.